# Does hard reload really works on location.reload(true)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frontend

I really need help with location.reload(true). Some guides say that location.reload(true) - works, others that it has no effect.

I do not know how to test it - and check whether this hard reload works or it is just a reload of the page.

Have you faced this question? Do you know the exact way to reproduce and test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that: in the network tab - in the size - you see word cached if it is not loaded from the server.

Seems that location.reload(true) works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.